# Show that $\epsilon ( integer(a/\epsilon) - integer(b/\epsilon) )= a - b + O(\epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$integer(a)$ = the integer part of a real number $a$. For example, $integer (\pi) =3$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and $a<b$ real numbers.

How to show that $$\epsilon ( integer(a/\epsilon) - integer(b/\epsilon)) = a - b + O(\epsilon)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of some computer language, let me use mathematical language.

Claim:
$$
\epsilon\left(\left\lfloor\frac{a}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor
- \left\lfloor\frac{b}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor\right) = a-b+O(\epsilon)\quad\text{as $\epsilon \to 0^+$}
$$
We will use this property of the integer part:
$$
x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x.
$$
First an upper bound
$$
\epsilon\left(\left\lfloor\frac{a}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor
- \left\lfloor\frac{b}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor\right) \le
\epsilon\left(\frac{a}{\epsilon}
- \frac{b}{\epsilon}+1\right)
= a-b+\epsilon
$$
Simlarly, prove a lower bound 
$$
\epsilon\left(\left\lfloor\frac{a}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor
- \left\lfloor\frac{b}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor\right) \ge
\epsilon\left(\frac{a}{\epsilon} - 1
- \frac{b}{\epsilon}\right)
= a-b-\epsilon
$$
I hope you can finish the proof from these two inequalities.